# How can I get the full grapejs HTML with html and head tags?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, grapejs

I can't find in the [documentation](https://grapesjs.com/docs/api/) how to get a *full* working html using grapejs. I have a config object:

```
export const configObject = {
  container: "#gjs",
  fromElement: false,
  height: "50rem",
  width: "auto",
  commands: { defaults: editorAssets.commands },
  canvasCss:
    ".gjs-selected {outline: 3px solid #556ee6 !important;} .gjs-toolbar {background-color: #556ee6 !important;} .gjs-badge__name {background-color: #556ee6 !important;}",
  storageManager: false,
  deviceManager: { devices: editorAssets.devices },
  layerManager: { appendTo: ".layers-container" },
  traitManager: { appendTo: ".settings-container" },
  blockManager: { appendTo: ".blocks-container", blocks: editorAssets.blocks },
  styleManager: {
    appendTo: ".styles-container",
    sectors: editorAssets.sectors,
  },
  panels: { defaults: editorAssets.panels },
  plugins: [parserPostCSS, grapesjscomponentcodeeditor],
  pluginsOpts: {
    [grapesjscomponentcodeeditor]: {
      appendTo: ".panel__right",
      preserveWidth: true,
      cleanCssBtn: false,
    },
  },
}
```

And then on the editor:

```
const editor = grapesjs.init({
  ...configObject,
  components: templateId ? currentTemplate.template : "",
})

setGetTemplateCode(() => () => {
  return `${editor.getHtml({
    cleanId: false,
  })}<style>${editor.getCss()}</style><script>${editor.getJs()}</script>`
})
```

This `.getHtml` function returns an incomplete HTML string, with meta tags not being inside a head tag, with no HTML tag, with no DOCTYPE, etc. How can I get a true full standard HTML that works and that can be rendered on an e-mail?

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
editor.Canvas.getDocument()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck

Comment: For some reason, this works in the Google Chrome dev tools console for me perfectly, but when I try to use it in the JS of my project's code it gives me some other object data with a "location" key, "hostname", "origin", "ancestorOrigins", etc.

Comment: @BryanMiller interesting hard to tell why without no code.  Could possibly be asynchronous. Maybe you need to await it?

Comment: Not sure.  FYI it seemed using a plain JS query to select the content inside the iframe worked too